# What are the prefixes for sextuple, septuple, octuple, etc. called?

Tags: word-request, prefixes

It's a simple question, really, but I have never known who to ask or what to Google.

Comment: Are these also used in your language? Many European languages use these prefixes to indicate numerals.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia calls these ["numeral prefixes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix), You might want to indicate if you mean a Greek numeral prefix, or a Latin numeral prefix.

Thats not really a technical linguistic term, just a simple description. It is rare enough that you would probably have to say "numeral prefixes, like hexa- septa- or octa-, ...." to make it clear what you mean.